# Magento crons with hour in cron expression not scheduling

Tags: magento, cronexpression

I have been trying to schedule a cron job at 1830 hours daily but it never is scheduled

```
<cron_expr>30 18 * * *</cron_expr>   //This never works
<cron_expr>0 18 * * *</cron_expr> //This also does not work
```

However when I schedule a cron using the minutes expression, it is always scheduled

```
<cron_expr>*/10 * * * *</cron_expr> //This surprisingly works!
```

I understand that Magento schedules crons using the UTC timezone, and the expressions that I have tried are to do with times in UTC.

Can someone help me with what am I missing out?

Comment: Try to check configuration System/Configuration/System/Cron against period of executing cron.php/cron.sh.

E.g. you executed cron.php/cron.sh every 30 min then you should set "Generate Shedules Every" to 30 min and "Schedule Ahead for" at least to 35 min.

Comment: Currently both generate schedules every 15 min and schedule ahead is for 60  minutes.

Comment: Ok it seems good. And how often you execute cron.php/cron.sh?

Comment: So I have nothing falls. Perhaps it would not support the 24-hour format, but it probably is not. Really do not know. Sorry.